# How to get around Mockito when thenReturn failing inside internal method

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am currently trying to unit test a spring boot Java project that was previously created. There is an bug in a method of a mocked class that is called from the method I'm trying to test. When thenReturn is returning an error due to that method being broken. Is there a way to make the broken method return the value I want and use it in the method I'm testing, since I'll get an error if it is actually called?

**EDIT:**

Code example below:

test class:

```
T mockedClass = mock(mockedClass.class);
//Mocked class is autowired
public class TestClass {

    private final idString = "idString"; //This is unchanged, must be a certain value

    @Test
    public void test() {
        T arg1 = new arg1(...);
        ReturnData r = new ReturnData(...); //creates JSON return data I want to be returned
        when(mockedClass.brokenMethod(arg1, idString)).thenReturn(r); //returns JSON return data with status key, status should be SUCCESS, but is ERROR
        T response = classToBeTested.testMethod();
    }
}
```

class that is tested:

```
@Autowired
T mockedClass;
public class classToBeTested {

    public void testedMethod() {
    ...
    //broken method for mocked class called here, but status returned is ERROR not SUCCESS due to a bug
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get a code example of the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Updated the question with a code example

Comment: so what you have would work (bad syntax aside). The mockito creates a blank Mock Object and would only return what you tell it.  The only way that returnMethod would return something that you didn't create, would be if you actually called the originating object (e.g. - you auto wired in a real class, not a mock one).  Unfortunately, I don't see that in the example code.